# How to make LossEvolutionPlot more detailed?

Tags: graphics, visualization, neural-networks

I use `NetTrain` to train a model,Then I got `net` and `LossEvolutionPlot`

```
{net, LossEvolutionPlot} = NetTrain[net,File["training_normalization_ForTF.h5"], MeanSquaredLossLayer[], {"TrainedNet", "LossEvolutionPlot"}, BatchSize -> 4096, TargetDevice -> "GPU", ValidationSet -> Scaled[0.22222], MaxTrainingRounds -> 200,
```

The expression of `LossEvolutionPlot` is:

```
p = Uncompress@Import@"https://wolfr.am/lNslN7ev"
```

[image]

It does not have picks,so how to make the plot more detailed?

Answer (score 1):

You can format the plot using `Show` like this:

```
Show[p, FrameTicks -> Automatic, FrameLabel -> {"batch", "loss"}, 
 ImagePadding -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: but MSE loss always bigger than zero.

Comment: @partida I think it is in log scale.